# Multiple form submissions on single page - only want to submit one but it is submitting them all

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, so this is a very strange problem and it has a lot of possible reasons so I'll try to include everything one would need to answer it but if there is anything else just tell me and i'll post it

So I have an app which lists 'wishes' basically just a blog/post model. Each wish has many votes, and votes belong to the wish. On my index page I would like to list all of the wishes and corresponding votes, a button to allow casting a vote, and a form to submit a new wish

This is the _new wish partial

```
<%= form_for( @wish, :remote => true) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, 'I Wish UChicago Had' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

it is remote because i want to use ajax to post it on the index page
here is the way i list the wishes, in a table with the name, votes and a button to vote

```
<tr>
<td> <%= w.title       %> </td>
<td> <%= w.author      %> </td>
<td> <%= w.count_votes %> </td>
<td> <%= render 'vote' %> </td>
<tr>
```

and finally the vote partial

```
<%= form_for(@vote) do |f| %>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.hidden_field :wish_id, :value => @w.id%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now here is the issue, here is a copy of the rails log when I try to create a new wish

```
Started POST "/wishes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-16 19:44:05 -0500
  Processing by WishesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FnrT95FCdv5fJs8AoxIMhrRjBk79wmWJ2s/RdsB43Pg=", "wish"=>{"title"=>"paul"}}
  AREL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "wishes" ("title", "body", "author", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ('paul', NULL, NULL, '2011-04-17 00:44:05.190203', '2011-04-17 00:44:05.190203')
Rendered wishes/create.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started POST "/votes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-16 19:44:05 -0500
  Processing by VotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FnrT95FCdv5fJs8AoxIMhrRjBk79wmWJ2s/RdsB43Pg=", "vote"=>{"wish_id"=>"1"}}
  Wish Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "wishes".* FROM "wishes" WHERE "wishes"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "votes" ("weight", "wish_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 1, '2011-04-17 00:44:05.321513', '2011-04-17 00:44:05.321513')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 62ms


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-16 19:44:05 -0500
  Processing by WishesController#index as HTML
  Wish Load (54.4ms)  SELECT "wishes".* FROM "wishes"
```

As you can see, the wishes posts correctly to `/wishes` and even renders the `create.js` correctly! but then it keeps going and renders the `/votes` post also! and this gets rendered as html as usual.

Why is it submitting both forms? I just want to submit one or the other?

***EDIT***_
here is the outputted HTML on the page

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td> paul </td>
<td>  </td>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/votes" class="new_vote" id="new_vote" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FnrT95FCdv5fJs8AoxIMhrRjBk79wmWJ2s/RdsB43Pg=" /></div>
  <div class="fields">
    <input id="vote_wish_id" name="vote[wish_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input id="vote_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Vote" />
  </div>
</form> </td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td> paul kaplan </td>
<td>  </td>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/votes" class="new_vote" id="new_vote" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FnrT95FCdv5fJs8AoxIMhrRjBk79wmWJ2s/RdsB43Pg=" /></div>
  <div class="fields">
    <input id="vote_wish_id" name="vote[wish_id]" type="hidden" value="2" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input id="vote_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Vote" />
  </div>
</form> </td>
<tr>
</table>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/wishes" class="new_wish" data-remote="true" id="new_wish" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FnrT95FCdv5fJs8AoxIMhrRjBk79wmWJ2s/RdsB43Pg=" /></div>


  <div class="field">
    <label for="wish_title">I Wish I Had</label>
    <input id="wish_title" name="wish[title]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input id="wish_submit" name="commmm" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the HTML output of the page.

Comment: jQuery, and JavaScript (obviously) run on the client side. The client side sees only the output of the server-side scripts (the (x)html ***not*** the Ruby). So, for JavaScript questions we *need* to see the outputted (x)html, rather than trying to infer that (x)html from the server-side script...and we *definitely* need to see the outputted jQuery script.

Comment: oh alright my bad, edited it to show the HTML

Comment: What does the jQuery look like? I'm, genuinely, not trying to be obtuse or a hindrance, but without that it's hard to diagnose what's going on. For JS questions we need, really, to see the outputted (x)html and the JS itself (albeit reduced to the problematic portion of the script(s)).

Comment: You have the same id on the first 2 form which is invalid and could produce a javascript error.  But true, we need some script to find out what the main problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been a while, but for completeness if anyone else hits this problem I figure I should put up my answer. basically the comments above where correct, I had 2 forms with the same id so it was submitting them both, and the javascript was messing it up.